# Arrange several movies next to each other on a raster programmatically

Tags: video

I'm looking for a way to playback a bunch of movies on a raster. For example, let's say we have 25 movies to be played on a (5x5) matrix. I want to be able to decide which movie is where at what time period (movies jump around on the raster during playback), so I would like some flexibility  which is why I would want to do this programmatically. Does anyone have any idea how I could do this? I was looking into FFmpeg, but not an expert there.

Thanks a lot for any advice on this!

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a tricky requirement, if you want to be able to change things in real time, or near real time.

The easiest way to do it programatically would be to have each video streamed individually to the platform displaying the videos and then simply move the windows on the display for each movie appropriately.

The problem with this approach is that you'll likely find, that most playback platforms, e.g. laptop browsers, mobile devices etc, will have a hard time playing this many videos simultaneously.

If this videos are very small and low bit rate, you may be able to do it.

If you are only actually interested in one of the videos as the key one people will watch you may be able to just stream two videos - one background video stream with 25 videos combined in a grid, and one extra video stream which is the size of one grid square. You can move the position of the second video to fit over one of the grid positions in the background video.

If none of this works for you then you will likely have to do the video manipulation on the server side - being aware that manipulating this many videos in real time, or near real time, will be processor intensive.

If you can process the video in advance then the using ffmpeg complex filters may work for you.

ffpmeg filters will allow you to combine videos into a grid using the '-filter_complex' option. See two examples from the ffmpeg wiki:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide

In the second one note the comment about aligning the zero timestamps:

> Be aware that frames are taken from each input video in timestamp order, so it is a good idea to pass all overlay inputs through a setpts=PTS-STARTPTS filter to have them begin in the same zero timestamp, such as [0:v]hflip,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[a][b]overlay.

This will produce your grid but for the whole video - to change it over time you would need to break the video up into sections and change the ffmpeg parameters to move the overlays around.